# XMLSchema namespace is ignored (JAXB unmarshal fails)

Tags: spring, kotlin, jaxb, spring-ws

I'm trying to unmarshal a complex payload for which I do not have a complete definition (just the wrapper, which then defines the actual varying content as

```
@XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
protected Object any;
```

Now, I've done this before in another project and it worked just fine, in a two step unmarshal - first do the wrapper, then access `any` as a `Node` and unmarshal that to the expected content (for which I had no xsd and I had to manually model into classes)

This time however, the content comes back namespaced and the only way I've gotten it to work is to add namespace to every `XmlRootElement`, `XmlElement`and `XmlType` in all of my own modeled structures. Obviously this is a huge pain and I tried to add an `XmlSchema` to the package that holds the domain objects mapping the Xml payload, but for some reason that is not picked up by the unmarshaller.

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(namespace = "http://mynamespace.com",
        elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package com.myproject.schema;
```

I've tried creating unmarshallers in multiple ways, none pick-up the XmlSchema in the package

```
val marshaller = Jaxb2Marshaller()
marshaller.setPackagesToScan("supplier.package", "com.myproject.schema")
```

or

```
val unmarshaller = JAXBContext.newInstance(myKClass.java).createUnmarshaller()
```

My (relevant) dependecies look like this

```
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:2.4.1")
implementation("org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:3.0.10.RELEASE")
implementation("javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:2.3.1")
implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.10.1")
```

EDIT:
So apparently the package-level annotation is not read because the package-info.java file seems to be excluded from the build (and so it's not picked up by the classloader). I've looked at the classes build from the xjc output and those do contain the package-info.

I'm still looking into why this is happening, maybe there's a flag for Gradle or the Kotlin plugin I can switch to get that included.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is fixed indeed by a package-level `XmlSchema` annotation. However, one must check that it is indeed picked-up when the class is loaded (reflection is your friend) and if not, keep in mind that `package-info.java` files must be put in your Java sources and not your Kotlin sources (seems obvious, but it's not always as obvious when you're a few hours down the rabbit hole).